# How can I optimize MySQL for massive batch inserts from a Java application?

Tags: java, mysql, optimization, batch-processing

I'm running some tests on a Windows 7 Pro 64-bit 
It has an i7-6700 and 8GB of RAM 
I'm accessing files from an SSD and processing them through a Java console application which transforms and loads them into a mySQL server on the same machine, but on a separate mechanical HDD.

I've disabled Page Filing 
I've set **innodb_buffer_pool_size** set from **8M** to **2G** 
I've set **innodb_thread_concurrency** set from **17** to **32** 
I've set **innodb_buffer_pool_instances** set from **8** to **16** 
I've set **max_connections** set from **151** to **256** 
For whatever reason, anything higher than that will cause the server to crash on start. I've checked the installation and MySQL reports back saying it's a AMD64 installation, but the memory limitations I'm encountering makes me wonder if it's really a 32-bit install.

I'm particularly having issue with this one object, Structure Below 
**CustomObject1** 
String custObj1str1 
String custObj1str2 
String custObj1str3 
String custObj1str4 
int custObj1int1 
int custObj1int2 
float[7] custObj1fltArr1 
float[7] custObj1fltArr2 
ArrayList custObj2

**CustomObject2** 
int custObj2int1 
float[4] custObj2fltArr1

I made a HashKey for custObj1 from custObj1str1, custObj1str2, custObj1str3, custObj1str4, custObj1int1, custObj1int2 and I use that as a primary key. This object goes into 4 separate tables.

**table1** 
int hashkey (Primary Key) 
varchar custObj1str1 
varchar custObj1str2 
varchar custObj1str3 
varchar custObj1str4 
int custObj1int1 
int custObj1int2

**table2** 
int hashkey (Primary Key) 
float custObj1fltArr1[0] ... float custObj1fltArr1[6]

**table3** 
int hashkey (Primary Key) 
float custObj1fltArr2[0] ... float custObj1fltArr2[6]

**table4** 
int hashkey (Primary Key, pt 1) 
int custObj2int1 (Primary Key, pt 2) 
float custObj1fltArr2[0] ... float custObj2fltArr1[4]

In Java, I'm doing prepared SQL statements with batch processing 
For table1 -> **"INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " + primaryKey + " = " + primaryKey** 
For table4 -> **"INSERT INTO table4 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " + primaryKey + " = " + primaryKey + " AND " + foreignKey + "=" + foreignKey** 
I believe that for table4 it's causing some data to be overwritten because it's so much data (over 30M records).

This is just for one day worth of data, I'm potentially going to have to manage 4 years worth.

[Image of Table Status (sensitive info redacted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzV6t.png) 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

** UPDATE **

I tried using mySQL on my MacBook Pro (Late 2013 with i7, 16GB RAM, and SSD). It was slow, but still substantially faster than the Windows machine.

[MacBook Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmp87.png) 
I set the methods that do the batch uploads as Synchronous in order to limit the amount of data that gets imported into the same table. Should I limit that on a per database basis, leave it as it is, or remove it completely? I'm using a 8 count thread pool, but I'd like to increase it.

Answer (score 0):

That Data_length is suspiciously close to 2^31.  What filesystem is mysql residing on?  NTFS should be OK, but I suspect FAT16 and FAT32 have limitations.  (Databases have grown faster than Windoz has.)

Let's see the log. And 32-bit would explain the crash (and it would be in the log). If 32-bit, back off on the 4 changes you mention, but have `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1500M`. Even if 64-bit and crashing, see if this will help.

To judge the batch inserts, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and how many row you are batching at once.

**OS limitation?**

First upgrade to 64-bit MySQL.  If that does not suffice...

See what file system is involved and see if there is a work-around for it.  Else...

*If* the problem is an OS limitation on file size, then there *may* be a workaround via MySQL.

- `ibdata1` can be actually a set of files, and you could limit each to, say, 1GB.  See the manual.  If you can't find it, I'll dig it out.
- A table can be `PARTITIONed` is some what such that each partition is small enough to fit in the OS limitation.  This requires `innodb_file_per_table=ON` and careful design of how to do the partitioning.  I need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and have a feel for what values are in each column before advising further.
- 5.7 allows specifying where to put each partition -- this would be handy if the entire drive had a limitation.  (As opposed to each *file*.)

Comment: My batch inserts are up to 1K in size, until all records are loaded.
I was log in the wrong error log before, (I moved directories), and it is indeed a 32-bit system.
File system is indeed NTFS.

Comment: I did not think NTFS stopped at 2G, but I suspect that is the problem.  Perhaps updating MySQL to 64-bit will fix it, but I worry that it might not.  Since day 1 (or nearly so), MySQL (even 32-bit) has handled huge files.  But it is always at the mercy of the OS limitations.

Comment: I added more options.